# how to add multiple classes in preact

Tags: reactjs, preact

I want to add multiple classes to a div.

```
import style from "../layout/main.css";

<div className={style.root style.root-left}>
```

Nor this is working

```
import "../layout/main.css";
<div className="root root-left">
```

I Have a little bit of experience with React. 2nd approach is what I normally do in React and it works...but in my Preact project nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are strings so you can use any way of concatenating strings.

In PReact you can use class and className interchangeably. [PReact Docs](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/differences-to-react#main-differences)

**Template literals:**

```js
<div className={`${style.root} ${style.root-left}`}>
```

**Split an array:**

*Good if you are rendering classes conditionally. You can push to the array based on the condition.*

```js
const classNames = [style.root, style.root-left];

<div className={classNames.join(' ')}>
```

*The + operator:*

```js
<div className={style.root + ' ' + style.root-left}>
```

Comment: I think you meant to "Join an array", not "Split [...]"? :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Preact works the same as React, you need to combine the two variables into a single string:

```
<div className={style.root+" "+style.root-left}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) if you have some conditions:

```
const allClass = classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar'
// module
const allClass = classNames(styles.foo, { [styles.bar]: true }); // => 'foo bar'
....
<div className={allClass}>
```

Or

```
<div className={`${style.root} ${style.root-left}`}>
```

suggested by @SamiElk